# How can i able to open whatsapp chat setting page?

Tags: android, whatsapp

i want to open chat setting page of whatsapp in my app. i don't know, it's possible or not,please help me if it's possible.

i tried with this code but i fail.

```
private void openWhatsApp() {

   Intent i = new Intent("com.whatsapp.SettingsChat");
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   i.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: as it seems, you can't. only `SettingsNotifications` do have an `IntentFilter` (and without `android.intent.action.MAIN` you won't be able to launch that `Activity` directly): https://github.com/GigaDroid/Decompiled-Whatsapp/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml